# Why can't I access this app with 127.0.0.1?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, port-forwarding

I have a .net core app in a docker container on Ubuntu on port 80 that seems to bind start listening on http://[::]:80 (ipv6)?.

I dont think this is .net specific but more the networking setup on the Ubuntu box.

when I do a wget to localhost, I get a reply with the following:

```
 wget localhost
--2022-03-14 17:47:59--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.27’
```

Whereas when I do a wget with the address 127.0.0.1, it gives me a 404 not found.

```
wget 127.0.0.1
--2022-03-14 17:50:10--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-03-14 17:50:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

From what I have read it is looking like this is due to ipv6 and my app being bound to ::

I have tried to disable ipv6 on the ubuntu box with no effect other than to also stop wget localhost returning anything.

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are your port forwarding rules in docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently listening to an IPv6 address in your container.

When using `http://localhost`, your OS will try both IPv4 and IPv6. You can verify this in your `/etc/hosts` file as localhost is mapped to the loopback addresses of both, IPv4 and IPv6 `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.

For example, this is part of my hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   danny

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
# [...]
```

If you want to access your container while listening only to an IPv6, you can access it with `http://localhost` as you already tried, or with the IPv6 loopback address `http://[::1]`. The brackets should be they sort of allow a URL interpreter that this part of the host and not a port separator.

For example, with `wget`, you would use it like so:

```
wget http://[::1]
```

Otherwise, you need to also listen to the IPv4 addresses. So binding it to `0.0.0.0:80` instead of `[::]:80` will allow you to access it with `http://127.0.0.1`.

---

Having said all the above, since you actually did receive a response when calling `http://127.0.0.1` (it was a 404, but it is still a response), that means that may have another service listening on port 80 on IPv4. So just switching it from `[::]:80` to `0.0.0.0:80` might give you an error that something else is using that port.

Comment: If you have something already listening on `127.0.0.1`, then you can arrange to listen on `127.0.0.2` (or any other address in the `127.?.?.?` range). First check that a few may already be in use.

Comment: Thanks guys, you pointed me in the right direction with this. It turned out that there was something obscure listening on port 80 that was returning 404, actually there was no issue with Docker and now I have removed what was listening on port 80, it is all fine. I went down a completely unnecessary rabbit hole with this!